# jQuery Modal on Click change element

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I'm making a crypto coin API project for my course, and I have an assignment to show modal if more than 5 coins are selected and choose one coin to remove and select the new one instead - all the coins I'm selecting are going to an array.
I'm trying to change the selected coin symbol on the #homeSection I've made for displaying the coins - but no luck changing on the section only on the modal.

I'll add the code I wrote for that:

```
$("#homeSection").on("click", "i", async function () {
    const coinId = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    const coin = await getMoreInfo(coinId);
    const c = coin.id;
    const star = $(this).hasClass("fa-regular fa-star toggle");

    if (star === true) {
        $(this).removeClass("fa-regular fa-star toggle");
        $(this).addClass("fa-solid fa-star toggle");
        if (toggledCoin.length < 5) {
            toggledCoin.push(c);
        }
        else {
            let content = "";
            for (let i = 0; i < toggledCoin.length; i++) {
                oldToggledCoin.push(toggledCoin[i]);
                let card = `<div id="modalDiv">
                    <div class="modal-card" id="modalCard">
                        <div class="card-body" id="modalCardBody">
                            <div class="${toggledCoin[i]}">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-star toggle"></i>
                            </div>
                            <h6 id="modalCoinName" class="card-title">${toggledCoin[i]}</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>`;
                content += card;
            }
            showModal(`More than 5 coins selected, to add ${coin.name} you must remove one coin:`, `${content}`, [
                {
                    label: "Got it!",
                    onClick: (modal) => {
                        toggledCoin.pop();
                        $(this).removeClass("fa-solid fa-star toggle");
                        $(this).addClass("fa-regular fa-star toggle");
                        console.log("The button was clicked!");
                    },
                    triggerClose: true
                },
            ]);
            toggledCoin.push(c);
            return;
        }
    }
    else {
        deleteCoin(c);
        $(this).removeClass("fa-solid fa-star toggle");
        $(this).addClass("fa-regular fa-star toggle");
    }
    console.log(toggledCoin);

    function showModal(titleHtml, contentHtml, buttons) {
        const modal = document.createElement("div");
        modal.classList.add("modal");
        modal.innerHTML = `
        <div class="modal__inner">
        <div class="modal__top">
            <div class="modal__title">${titleHtml}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal__content">${contentHtml}</div>
        <div class="modal__bottom"></div>
    </div >
        `;

        for (const button of buttons) {
            const element = document.createElement("button");
            element.setAttribute("type", "button");
            element.classList.add("modal__button");
            element.textContent = button.label;
            element.addEventListener("click", () => {
                if (button.triggerClose) {
                    $(".modal").remove();
                    // document.body.removeChild(modal);
                }
                button.onClick(modal);
            });
            modal.querySelector(".modal__bottom").appendChild(element);
        }
        // document.body.appendChild(modal);
        $("#homeSection").append(modal);
        // Append to homeSection

        $(".modal").on("click", "i", function () {
            // document.body.removeChild(modal);
            $(".modal").remove();
            const thisCoin = $(this).parent().attr("class");
            alert(thisCoin);
            const homeSec = $(document.body).children("#homeSection");
            const that = $(this);
            if (star === true) {
                $(this).removeClass("fa-solid fa-star toggle");
                $(this).addClass("fa-regular fa-star toggle");
                deleteCoin(thisCoin);
                console.log("Deleted", thisCoin);
            }
            console.log(toggledCoin);
            console.log("Old", oldToggledCoin);
            const missing = findMissing(oldToggledCoin, toggledCoin);
            console.log("Missing", missing);
            console.log($(homeSec).find(missing));
            
        });
    }
});
```

I took this modal from youtube.
Any hint will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: How about posting the entire code to be able to replicate?